# When writing a Visual Studio 2022 extension, how do I alter UI for files in the Solution Explorer?

Tags: visual-studio, vs-extensibility

The company I'm working for has very specific naming schemes and processes, which lead juniors or developers new to the company to make mistakes. We want to colour highlight certain files in the Solution Explorer based on whether they match a regex, and offer extra options in the context menu on those files.

I have some experience with VS extensions with older versions of VS, but things seem to have changed a lot. I can't even figure out how to get an instance of the UI hierarchy for the Solution Explorer.

I'd appreciate any info on:

1. How to get an instance of the UI hierarchy for the Solution Explorer
2. How to change the colour of files in the hierarchy
3. How to add a context menu to files in the hierarchy

Comment: You might get answer to some of your questions from this project: https://github.com/Therena/ConEmuIntegration/blob/master/ConEmuIntegration/SolutionExplorer/OpenFolderButtonItemNode.cs